# Interpolating 1D Gaussian into 2D Gaussian

Tags: matlab, interpolation

Let's say I have a 1D Gaussian function.
Its length is 600.

I want to interpolate it into a 2D Gaussian of the size 600 X 600.

This is the code I wrote (OTFx is the Gaussian Function, OTF - 2d Interpolated Function):

```
[x, y] = meshgrid([-300:299], [-300:299]);
r = sqrt((x .^ 2) + (y .^ 2));

OTF = interp1([-300:299], OTFx, r(:), 'spline');
OTF = reshape(OTF, [600, 600]);
```

The problem is I get Overshoot at the end:
[image]

How can I prevent this overshoot?
Is there better interpolating algorithm for monotonic descending functions?

**NOTE:** I am looking for a generic solution for interpolating a 1D function into a 2D radially symmetric function, the Gaussian is just an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: based on your clarification, it's clear what's going on.  You are trying to interpolate a function beyond the range of available data -- i.e. you are going from interpolation to extrapolation.  Splines are going to result in the overshoot that you are observing.  The solution is simply to make sure that your 1D function has values in the interval [min(r), max(r)].  Note that in the original data, max(r) is about 424, while the function you are interpolating is defined on the range [-300,299]

```
% Simulated overshoot, see left figure:
x1d = [-300:299];
[x,y]=meshgrid(x1d,x1d);
r = sqrt(x.^2+y.^2);
gsn1d = exp(-x1d.^2/500);
lowpass = @(x)(x1d > -x & x1d < x);
gsn1dcutoff = ifft(fftshift(lowpass(10).*fftshift(fft(gsn1d))));
plot(gsn1dcutoff)
OTF2d = reshape(interp1(x1d,gsn1dcutoff,r(:),'spline'),[length(x1d),length(x1d)]);
mesh(OTF2d)

% Quick and dirty fix, see right figure:
x1dExtended = linspace(min(x1d*sqrt(2)),max(x1d*sqrt(2)),ceil(length(x1d)*sqrt(2)));
gsn1dE = exp(-x1dExtended.^2/500);
% ^^^ note that this has 600*sqrt(2) points and is defined on the diagonal of your square.   Now we can low-pass filter in the freq. domain to add ripple in space domain:
lowpass = @(x)(x1dExtended > -x & x1dExtended < x);
gsn1dcutoff = -real(ifft(fftshift(lowpass(10).*fftshift(fft(gsn1dE)))));
plot(gsn1dcutoff)
OTF2d = reshape(interp1(x1dExtended,gsn1dcutoff,r(:),'spline'),[length(x1d),length(x1d)]);
mesh(OTF2d)
```

[alt text http://img54.imageshack.us/img54/8255/clipboard01vz.png](http://img54.imageshack.us/img54/8255/clipboard01vz.png)

Comment: Ok, Actually OTFx is estimated from an image, yet it's identical up to a constant and epsilon to a "Gaussian".

Try the following to replicate it. Create a Gaussian of length 21.
Convert it using fft with zero padding to the length 600. Try to interpolate it to have a 2D Gaussian as you would convert 2D Gaussian into frequency domain.

The question is, Is there an alternative way doing it?
Maybe a better algorithm, Applying some Constraints etc...

It's something similar to "Ringing" effect.

Thanks.

Comment: See my updated answer.  I don't think other interpolation algorithms will be better at extrapolating beyond available data, but feel free to look up help for interp1 and play with different algorithms.  The main point is: to avoid surprises, make sure you are providing sufficient data for interpolation.

Comment: Thank you for you response.
Maybe if I shed some more light on the problem you may assist me even more.
The interpolated function must be positive everywhere. Generally it should be Monotonic Descending.

I'm starting with something similar to 1D Gaussian of the length 21 then "FFT" it into 600 (Or whatever length I want using zero padding).
What I want is the best 600X600 2D interpolation of it in the Frequency Domain. As a test case we can take a "Pure" 1D Gaussian of the length 21 and try to interpolate it as close as possible to 600X600 2D DFT of 21X21 2D Gaussian.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Leo is right in his diagnosis. I'd like to suggest a simpler (I hope) remedy: to do what you want to do (which is basically rotate a Gaussian around its symmetry axis) and to get a reasonable answer in a 600x600 square you need a Gaussian 600*sqrt(2)=849 pixels long. If you can do that, then all further thttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443046/interpolating-1d-gaussian-into-2d-gaussianrickery is not necessary.

**Edit**: In other words: if you rotate something 600 pixels wide around its center, you get a circle 600 pixels in diameter. You want to cover a 600x600 *square*. For that you need a circle 849 pixels in diameter, since this is the diagonal of the square.

Comment: In fact, this is exactly what my "quick and dirty fix" is doing; it probably needs to be more explicit, since the fix is mixed in with the old code simulating the cutoff.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: What you basically suggest is if you want a 600X600 interpolation with Polar symmetry do interpolation of length 849 and crop only 600X600?
Thanks.

Comment: @Drazick: probably not. The point is: if you rotate something 600 pixels wide around its center, you get a circle 600 pixels in diameter. You want to cover a 600x600 square. For that you need a circle 849 pixels in diameter, since this is the diagonal of the square. I've added this to by answer's body, for posterity ;-)

Comment: The idea is to make something as comparable as possible to the 2D DFT of Gaussian function padded to 600X600 (Originally it was 21X21).

What would you do, DFT of the 1D into 849, make the rotation and then crop or live with the "Overshooting"?
Thanks.

Comment: How can I at least create a constrain of positivity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the particular case of the gaussian, you may compute the gaussian by using the fact that it is separable:

```
OTF2(x,y) = exp( - x^2 - y^2) = exp( - x^2) * exp( - y^2) = OTFx(x) * OTFx(y)
```

So you still just need to store just OTFx in memory.

Comment: I took Gaussian as an example. The real problem is interpolating 1D function into a 2D Radially Symmetric function.

Comment: Ok, I get it... you should edit your question accordingly. The overshoot seems to come from the mirroring - is there an option in matlav's interp for that?

Comment: Wow... there was a time I was coding in matlab :-)